# Steps to finding a limit with squeeze theorem

Tags: calculus, limits

How to find the limit of:

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{n+\sin^2n}$

using squeeze theorem?
Because $0\le \sin^2n \le 1 $,  I find $a_n=\sqrt[n]{n}$ (which is equal to 1) and $c_n=\sqrt[n]{n+1}$, but I don't know how to prove that second formula is also a 1. Could someone help me solve it please? Thank you!

Comment: How do you know $\lim \sqrt[n]{n}=n$?  You can't just assume.  The proof of $\lim \sqrt[n]{n+1}$ isn't much different.

Comment: If you know that $2^{1/n} \rightarrow 1$ and $n^{1/n} \rightarrow 1,$ then you can use the fact that $\sqrt[n]{n} \leq \sqrt[n]{n + {\sin}^2 n} \leq \sqrt[n]{n+n} = 2^{1/n}n^{1/n},$ and note that the left side approaches $1$ and the right side approaches $1 \cdot 1 = 1.$

Comment: $n^{1/n} \lt (n+1)^{1/n} \lt (2n)^{1/n}=2^{1/n}n^{1/n}.$

Comment: Thank you both! Easier than I thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hint:

$$n<n+1\leq 2n\implies \sqrt[n]{n}<\sqrt[n]{n+1}\leq \sqrt[n]{2n}=\sqrt[n]{2}\cdot\sqrt[n]{n}.$$

Comment: (+1) Exactly what I gave in a comment, but your answer came first!

Comment: Thank you, now it seems obvious!